# How does currying work in ReactJS with setState hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React, and I'm building a personal portfolio with React and Material-UI as my first project using what I've learned in the last few weeks.

While trying to build a simple toggler to have a side-nav pop in from the right side on button click, I got a "Error: too many re-renders" error in React with the following relevant code in Navbar.js:

```
// states
const [state, setState] = useState({
    right: false
})
const toggleSlider = (open) => {
    setState({right: open})
}

// some lines of code after...

<Toolbar>
     <IconButton onClick={toggleSlider(true)}>
          <ArrowBack style={{ color: "tomato" }} />
     </IconButton>

     <Drawer anchor="right" open={state.right}>
          {sideList()}
     </Drawer>
</Toolbar>
```

After doing some research, it turns out I either need to use an arrow function for the `onClick` handler for `<IconButton>`, or I use a curried function for `toggleSlider()` in order to avoid the React re-render error:

```
// states
const [state, setState] = useState({
    right: false
})
const toggleSlider = (open) => () => {
    setState({right: open})
}
```

My question is: how do curried functions work, and why does changing the `onClick` handler to an arrow function or make the handler a curried function stop the React re-render error? Why does it prevent React from rendering the component over and over again, as my code did before I added the curried function?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

When you are passing the name of the function to onClick event, you are basically binding the event handler of the onClick onto your function.

When you use parenthesis after the function, you are executing the function, not binding it.

When you executes your function, it will change the state of **right** variable, which React will interpret as a change and will re-render.

When React re-renders, your function executes again.
Then the infinite cycle happens.

The pattern that you are using should be called **inline function** when you are using **=> fat arrow symbol**. It also binds the fat arrow function to the event handler and not executing the function. Therefore, it won't re-render.

Comment: By binding the fat arrow function to the event handler, do you mean the arrow function is binded to the `onClick` event handler, so that the function isn't simply executed every time React re-renders?

Comment: @AaronLi yea, that's it. if you use () bracket...in normal js that means you are executing the function.  and another thing , currying is not actually a correct term here. currying means a function returns a function with another parameter so you can chain parameter to execute it without using multiple parameters. if you have used higher order components you might know pattern like `withStyles(tableStyle)(TableComponent)`. thats currying.

Answer (score 0):

By using `onClick={toggleSlider(true)}` youre calling `toggleSlider(true)` and put its returning value on the `onClick`, which is not how it should work. Use this instead:

```
<IconButton onClick={() => toggleSlider(true)}>
    <ArrowBack style={{ color: "tomato" }} />
</IconButton>
```

A bit more cleaned up:

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

<Toolbar>
     <IconButton onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>
          <ArrowBack style={{ color: "tomato" }} />
     </IconButton>

     <Drawer anchor="right" open={open}>
          {sideList()}
     </Drawer>
</Toolbar>
```

Although this doesnt actually toggle, it just opens it. If you want to toggle, use:

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

<Toolbar>
     <IconButton onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
          <ArrowBack style={{ color: "tomato" }} />
     </IconButton>

     <Drawer anchor="right" open={open}>
          {sideList()}
     </Drawer>
</Toolbar>
```

Comment: I did implement the "cleaner" way as you did as well, I was just trying to figure out why using an arrow function for the `onClick` (or using a curried function as I did) works to stop re-rendering. Is it because the function is now binded to the event handler of `onClick` and will only fire when the `IconButton` component is actually clicked?

Comment: Yea, so the arrow function in the `onClick` makes it the handler of that action. If you dont use the arrow function, it will first execute the function youve given and use the result as the `onClick` handler, which doesnt work. Basically you did `onClick={undefined}` before. You need to provide a function that can be executed on click, not a value.